# Como passo enctype="multipart/form-data" pelo $.post?

Tags: jquery

Como faço para mandar um formulário via $.post com um input tipo file onde o form tenha enctype="multipart/form-data"?
Todos os outros campos fazem a inserção o problema que o arquivo não passo pois não ler como enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como passar enctype="multipart/form-data" com $.post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264917/como-passar-enctype-multipart-form-data-com-post)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Resposta curta: **não passa!**

O método `jQuery.post()` "aka" `$.post()` foi desenhado para "carregar dados do servidor utilizando uma solicitação `HTTP POST`" os parâmetros do tipo [String](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String) ou [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) são opcionais, embora estes parametros sirvam apenas para atender requisitos da solicitação é muito comum utilizá-los para enviar dados ao servidor más, não há suporte a `multiparty/form-data` neste método.

A estrutura deste método é a seguinte:

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

Onde todos os parâmetros com exceção da `url` são opcionais. [Documentação oficial](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

> Como fazer então?

Simples, utilize o método `jQuery.ajax()` "aka" `$.ajax()` que aceita inúmeras opções de configuração. [Documentação oficial](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

A estrutura do método `$.ajax()` segue a seguinte base:

```
jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] )
```

Como podes notar o parâmetro de configurações ([PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)) são opcionais más, não é necessário declarar explicitamente o primeiro argumento `url` caso você defina configurações e esta tenha (contenha) uma "url" exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://awesomedomain.com'
})
```

> Um exemplo completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titulo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
        <input type="text" name="extraField"><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="files"><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="files"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit">
    </form>

    <!-- load jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // evento de "submit"
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
                // parar o envio para que possamos faze-lo manualmente.
                event.preventDefault();
                // capture o formulário
                var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
                // crie um FormData {Object}
                var data = new FormData(form);
                // caso queira adicionar um campo extra ao FormData
                // data.append("customfield", "Este é um campo extra para teste");
                // desabilitar o botão de "submit" para evitar multiplos envios até receber uma resposta
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
                // processar
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    url: "/coolurl/upload",
                    data: data,
                    processData: false, // impedir que o jQuery tranforma a "data" em querystring
                    contentType: false, // desabilitar o cabeçalho "Content-Type"
                    cache: false, // desabilitar o "cache"
                    timeout: 600000, // definir um tempo limite (opcional)
                    // manipular o sucesso da requisição
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        // reativar o botão de "submit"
                        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
                    },
                    // manipular erros da requisição
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        // reativar o botão de "submit"
                        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Outros tópicos similares aqui na comunidade:

- [Fazer upload de arquivo com AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax)
- [Enviar arquivos de upload com AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158955/enviar-arquivos-de-upload-com-ajax/158963)
- [Validando input file com requisição ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136303/validando-input-file-com-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax/136318)